# Default Kendo Grid filtering doesn't work in one of projects, works in another

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a hard time figuring out why the default filtering doesn't work in one of my projects.
  The grid code looks perfectly similar, controller methods too.  **In one of the projects it works flawlessly, in other one the "filter" button appears but is not clickable.**

Any clues what might be causing it?
Client side filtering is not an option for me since the amount of data is huge.

Filterable project rendered html for the filter button:

```
<a class="k-grid-filter" href="javascript:void(0)" tabindex="-1"><span class="k-icon k-filter"></span></a>
```

Unfilterable project rendered html for the filter button:

```
<a class="k-grid-filter" tabindex="-1"><span class="k-icon k-filter"></span></a>
```

The grid signature looks identical in both projects:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyModel>()
      .Name("grid")
      .Columns(columns =>
      { 
        //bounding several columns, columns.Bound(x => x.Field);
      })
      .Filterable()
      .DataSource(dataSource =>
      {
          dataSource              
              .Ajax()
              .PageSize(20)
              .Model(model => { model.Id(product => product.Id); })
              .Read(read => read.Action("Index", "Home"))
      }))
```

Controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            var data = repository.GetAll<MyModel>();
            return Json(data.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: Have you checked the dev tools in the browser to see if you are getting any errors thrown to the console. Without seeing the two different grids it is difficult to tell where the issue may be. Also do you have any javascript that is maybe overriding the filtering or is the type you are trying to filter on a complex type e.g. not a string, datetime etc. but a list or an array etc.

Comment: the problem ended up being jquery-ui.js include.

Comment: glad to see you got it working in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone running into a similar problem, my problem was in the included javascript files, *jquery-ui.js* to be prescise. Commenting it out solved this particular grid problem. Good luck!